# Codeigniter, use same database connection when extending models

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

Relatively new to frameworks, MVC and OOP in general... so here is a basic question:

If I have Account model like this:

```
class Account_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->sybase = $this->load->database( 'sybase', TRUE );
    }
}
```

Then a controller calls **two** models which both extend from the Account model:

```
class Account_List_Model extends Account_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $sql = "SELECT ....";
        return $this->sybase->query( $sql )->result();
    }
}
```

And

```
class Account_Details_Model extends Account_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $sql = "SELECT ....";
        return $this->sybase->query( $sql )->result();
    }
}
```

My question is will they both use the same connection? I was planning it this way to use the same connection but now I am thinking that because the parent gets constructed twice it will use two separate connections. Maybe I am over-thinking this. Maybe I am under-thinking this.
If not, is a singleton the only answer or are there other ways?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter opens the connection when you load the Database class, so there is only a single connection in use (unless you connect to two or more databases).

It is also okay to have several methods in your model.  I usually use one model associated with a particular database table (sometimes more than one if I use joins with closely related tables).

I think that you are good to carry on.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have other methods like get and set. I just put the query in the constructor to simplify the example.